# Resource board game with villagers, huts, and breeding

Tags: identify-this-game

About 5 years ago I played a 4-player board game.  It had villager pieces that you could assign to huts and they would breed.  There were resources like wood, and a trade/merchant/ports area where you would get cards that reminded me of development cards in Catan.

I think the win condition was victory points like Catan.

What was the board game?

Comment: It might be [Agricola](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/31260/agricola), but probably not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sounds like [Stone Age](https://www.zmangames.com/en/products/stone-age/) by Z-Man games.

Copied from the website:

> **THE BEGINNING OF TIME**
>
> Life was hard in the early days of human history. Our ancestors were
> hard workers, but through ingenuity learned to make much of this work
> easier. Over time, they developed tools to collect resources and
> develop human civilization. In Stone Age, you take on the role of a
> human in this bygone era. Beginning with archaic tools, you collect
> wood, stone, and gold to attain higher levels of knowledge and build
> sturdier structures. With resources being scarce, you must compete for
> the limited number of spaces on the board that produce them while also
> gathering food to feed your growing tribe. Through diligence and
> insight, you can forge your way through the early days of recorded
> history and build the foundation of human civilization.  ￼
>
> **CARVE VICTORY IN STONE**
>
> Stone Age is an engaging and accessible game where players take turns
> placing figures on board spaces to perform actions and gather
> resources. There are a limited number of spaces, so you must determine
> the best actions to take each round. It’s up to you to develop your
> tribe by gathering resources, constructing new buildings, and
> advancing their culture while also maintaining enough food to feed
> your people. Strike the right balance to create the most advanced
> civilization and lead your people to a better life!

Comment: Perhaps you could add some details about *Stone Age* that made you think this is the correct game?

Comment: I saw this on Tabletop if it helps the answerer or OP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hh0q958qzRs

Comment: @ZeissIkon He provided a link which will surely jog the person's memory. They're describing Stone Age to a T, and repeating their description and saying "all of which this game has" is pointless extra text.

Comment: @JKreft Providing information from a link is helpful as it can let users find information using the sites search function or without having to follow the link. It is also useful in helping prevent link rot in case the link ever goes bad.

Comment: I copied the game description from the website to address the earlier comments here

Comment: @JKreft - Providing context to links is essential to a [good answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).